# Accordion stopped working, will not collapse or Expand

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

This is my first post on Stackoverflow, i have read answers to problems here for quite some time, and now need to ask a question.

I have been looking through this for hours and cannot find whats wrong. Its a program for a conference, made using *Joomla*. The javascript goes into the *index.php* and the program code below is in the article.

```
// ]]>

  // BEGIN: ACCORDION FOR PROGRAM //

// <![CDATA[
//list of target elements
var list = $$('#accordion .content');
//list elements to be clicked on
var headings = $$('#accordion .speaker');
//array to store all of the collapsibles
var collapsibles = new Array();
headings.each(function(heading, i) {
  //for each element create a slide effect
  var collapsible = new Fx.Slide(list[i], {
    duration: 500,
    transition: Fx.Transitions.linear
  });
  //and store it in the array
  collapsibles[i] = collapsible;
  //add event listener
  heading.onclick = function() {
    //open current element
    collapsible.toggle();
    //hide the rest
    for (var j = 0; j < collapsibles.length; j++) {
      if (j != i) collapsibles[j].slideOut();
    }
    return false;
  }
  //collapse all of the list items
  collapsible.hide();
});
//collapse all
$('collapse-all').onclick = function() {
  headings.each(function(heading, i) {
    collapsibles[i].hide();
  });
}
//expand all
$('expand-all').onclick = function() {
  headings.each(function(heading, i) {
    collapsibles[i].show();
  });
}
// ]]>
// END: ACCORDION FOR PROGRAM //
```

---

Here is a link to the accoridon program where I have the issue: http://www.tbliconference.com/index.php/upcoming-conferences/tbli-usa-2014#rt-showcase-panel

It has worked fine untill now, but seems to not open or close anymore? 
Any Advise welcome.

Thanks for any help

Stephen

Comment: You're getting a script error showing up in mootools-more.js - check your console and you'll see the error "cannot call method retrieve of null". The script error is most likely breaking other scripts on your page, meaning any javascript that would be necessary for your expandables.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply. I'll check this and let you know how it went. Stephen